# authors informations in a conference paper

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ieeetran, affiliation

I am working on an IEEE paper and the conference has mentioned to have the authors name in two columns (first and second author in the left and the third one in the in the right column). Here is the code that gives the information combined.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{1.5\baselineskip}
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\begin{document}
\title{TITLE XXXX}
\author
{\IEEEauthorblockN{Auhtor 1 $^1$$^*$, Author 2 $^2$$^*$, Auhtor3 $^3$$^*$}
\IEEEauthorblockA{ $^1$$^,$$^3$ Auhtor 1 and Author2 Affiliation .\\\  Author3  Affiliation$$^3$} 
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
balabalalalalalalalalalalal
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

The conference doesn't want to have the information combined How can I do it ??

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Related  ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Please edit the question to get a MWE and please add code style.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE XXXX}

\author{%
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Auhtor 1 $^*$, Author 2}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Auhtor 1 and Author2 Affiliation} 
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 3}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Author3  Affiliation}%
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
balabalalalalalalalalalalal
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```